# application Initialization webapi always requesting default.aspx

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to configure IIS to request a custom URL to warm up my webapi.

My config is like this.

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false">
      <add initializationPage="/api/transaction/5" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

This is working but IIS also calls the root web app (/default.aspx) to warm up as well. And I'm wondering how to remove this call as I don't need it.

Thanks for you help!

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this config section is working with collection of initialization elements. Try to clear this collection before adding your page:

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false">
<clear/>
<add initializationPage="/api/transaction/5" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it did not fix the issue.